# Debug a process in a VM

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, virtual-machine, windows-xp

I'm developing a program in C++ and I'm facing a problem. When I run it on my development (Win 10) machine, it works fine. As it also has to run on Windows XP, I installed Windows XP in VMWare and tried to run it, but it crashes. It's been compiled with the latest Visual Studio toolset for Windows XP, so this is not the problem. There's not much info about the crash on the machine.

How do I debug it remotely? I'll probably need to attach it to Visual Studio 2015s debugger, but if there's another solution, I won't be against it.

Comment: I'd install Visual Studio into the VM and debug directly from there.

Comment: Make sure that your XP machine has the proper Microsoft DLLs installed that you need to support a program built in VS2015.

Comment: @ChrisF Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support Windows XP.

Comment: @Logicrat It doesn't even use the standard C library, I exactly know what libraries it uses.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Can you get it to compile in an earlier version of VS?

Comment: It makes use of some C++11 features that I'm not sure they were supported back then.

Comment: You can use `windbg` to debug remotely, but whether that will work on a VM depends a little bit on whether the VM can produce output to a real serial port or network device or not - and the rest of your machine's ability to connect to said port.

Comment: When I built a .EXE using MSVC++ 6, it would run on various Windows versions (XP, 7, 8, 10) so long as I had MFC42.DLL and friends handy. Likewise, when I've built an .EXE using MSVC2010, it runs on Windows XP, 7, 8, or 10 so long as the executable can find MFC100.DLL and friends. You don't have to compile on an older system to build a program that is compatible with older systems.

Comment: @Logicrat I already said that the program was compiled successfully for Win XP and newer on my VS 2015, but at some point of its execution (on Win XP only) it crashes and I want to know what caused it.

Comment: Have you tried running the remote tools on your VM? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48155

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Visual Studio Remote Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on a machine that has problems and connect to it from your Visual Studio. After that you will be able to debug a remote process from your PC.

The latest remote debugger support Windows 7 and newer, so you might end up installing older version from VS 2013 or 2010 that would support Windows XP.